# Do I get an advantage from having a shield on my back in Demon's Souls

Tags: demons-souls

In Demon's Souls, do I get any advantage from carrying a shield on my back?

Also, do I get any bonuses from items equipped in my non-active equipment slot? For example, I have a sword and a shield equipped in my active equipment slot, and another alternate sword is equipped in my non-active equipment slot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In regards to your first question, **yes**. So long as the shield is in your active equipment slot, you will receive bonuses from it. The easiest way to test this is with the [Adjudicators Shield](http://demonssouls.wikidot.com/adjudicator-s-shield), which grants you health regeneration.

As for your second question, **no**. You only receive bonuses from the equipment in your active equipment
 slot.